# How to set up widget with Click to show Master/Slave Checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to write a prototype for a widget that contains 2 sides. On the left side is a list of interest groups, on the right side are the associated interest topics. (i.e. Pets on the left, Birds, Dogs, Cats, on the right). The data is populated by an AJAX call to an endpoint that's making a call to the Twitter API.

I'm not sure I'm approaching this correctly and would like some advice on how to get this set up the "Angular way". I was planning on using a similar approach to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thr3ee/83cvu/) for having the master/slave checkboxes setup. Below is my current code.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="interests">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twitter Interests</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" content="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="InterestController as interestCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <label>Interests</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <ul id="groups">
                <li group-listing group="{{ group }}" ng-repeat="group in (groups | filter: search) track by $index">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div topic-listing topic="{{ topic }}" ng-repeat="topic in topics track by $index">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**groupListing.html**

```
<div ng-click="showTopics(group)">{{ group }}</div>
```

**interestListing.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="topic.isChecked">{{ topic }}
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('interests', ['ngRoute']);

app.service('InterestService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var getInterests = function (query) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/interests?=' + query
        });
    };

    return {
        getInterests: getInterests
    }
}]);

app.controller('InterestController', ['$scope', 'InterestService', function ($scope, InterestService) {
    var results = [];
    var interests = {};
    var resultArray;
    var group;
    var topic;

    $scope.topics = [];

    $scope.showTopics = function (group) {
        $scope.topics = interests[group];
    };

    InterestService.getInterests().then(function (result) {
        results = result.data.data;

        _.each(results, function (result) {
            resultArray = result.name.split('/');
            group = resultArray[0];
            topic = {};
            topic.name = resultArray[1];
            topic.isChecked = false;

            if (_.has(interests, group)) {
                interests[group].push(topic);
            } else {
                interests[group] = [];
                interests[group].push({ name: 'All of ' + group, isChecked: false });
                interests[group].push(topic);
            }
        });

        $scope.groups = _.keys(interests);
    });
 }]);

app.directive('groupListing', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            group: "@"
        },
        controller: 'InterestController',
        templateUrl: 'templates/groupListing.html'
    }
});

app.directive('interestListing', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            topic: "@"
        },
        controller: 'InterestController',
        templateUrl: 'templates/interestListing.html',
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle of you own with this code in it? You can hardcode a json response in it so that the page works. Also, is what you are trying to achieve hiding/showing things on the right when things on the left are clicked? Your question doesn't really specify what functionality you're trying to implement other than master/slave checkbox. You can check out Angular-UI for master/slave checkbox functionality.

Comment: @EliteOctagon yes thats exactly what Im attempting to do. I will create the JS Fiddle right now. From the Angular Batamarang scope inspector in Dev Tools I see that the $scope.topics seems to be isolated to each group, so the ng-click functionality isnt updating the top level scope that I'm trying to get the interestListing ng-repeat to hit. Regardless of whether or not I get the functionality to work, I'm still very interested in whether or not I'm using the right approach, since this is my first Angular project.

Comment: Here's the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsR9n/8/). I'm having trouble getting it to work, maybe because of the external js files?

Comment: In the fiddle you are injecting InterestService into the controller, but you commented out the service in the code... so thats your initial problem

Comment: @EliteOctagon just updated the code and removed the InterestService